# Python 3 argparse call function

Tags: function, python-3.x, argparse

Need help understanding argparse use case in Python 3. Trying to write a simple program that uses arguments to call various functions. For example:

[Program] [Action] [Optional argument]

```
nachos.py delete 20394739
- or -
nachos.py -d 20394739

nachos.py search 30459389
- or -
nachos.py -s 30459389

nachos.py list
- or -
nachos.py -l
```

Trying to figure out how to implement this with Python 3. Please help. Thank you!

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example list of options')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--delete', action='delete', help='Delete ID')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--search', action='search', help='Search ID')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', action='list', help='List all ID')
args = parser.parse_args()

def (some function to handle each case)
```

*** UPDATE ***

This seems to work so far, but checking against a potentially long list of if statements seems slow and clunky. Is there no way to do it with a function which would seem more specific and too the point?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example list of options', add_help=True)
parser.add_argument('-d', '--delete', dest='command', action='store_const', const='delete', help='Delete ID')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--search', dest='command', action='store_const', const='search', help='Search ID')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', dest='command', action='store_const', const='list', help='List all ID')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.command == 'delete':
        print('Run delete')
elif args.command == 'search':
        print('Run search')
else:
        print('Run list')
```

Comment: You might consider `getopt` instead - you will be able to easily define a switch with calls to your defined function(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to review the meaning of the `action` parameter in the `argparse` docs.

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--delete', action='delete', help='Delete ID')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--search', action='search', help='Search ID')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', action='list', help='List all ID')
```

Those are not valid values.  Valid strings are things like 'store' (default), 'append', 'store_true'.  They refer to defined `argparse` Actions, not your functions.

If I change your parser to:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example list of options')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--delete', help='Delete ID')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--search', help='Search ID')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', action='store_true',help='List all ID')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

these inputs will produce an args that displays like:

```
nachos.py --delete 20394739
nachos.py -d 20394739
args.delete # '20394739'

nachos.py --search 30459389
nachos.py -s 30459389
args.search # '30459389'

nachos.py --list
nachos.py -l
args.list   # True
```

You need to check these values after parsing to decide what action to take.  `argparse` figures out what your users wants.  It's your responsibility to act on it.

While learning and debugging it's a good idea to do

```
print(args)

In [194]: print(parser.parse_args('--delete 2039 --search 304 -l'.split()))
Namespace(delete='2039', list=True, search='304')

In [195]: print(parser.parse_args('-d 2039'.split()))
Namespace(delete='2039', list=False, search=None)
```

to see how the parsing matches with the inputs.

There are more elaborate ways of doing this, with things like `subparsers` and `set_defaults`, but I think you need to understand the basic `argparse` workings first.

---

The argparse docs under the subparsers section talks about dispatching to a command [(subcommand setdefaults)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands). Here's a variant on that using `store_const`.

```
In [2]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser();
In [3]: parser.add_argument('-d')
In [4]: def foo(args):
   ...:     print(args)
In [5]: parser.add_argument('-f',action='store_const',const=foo)
```

With `store_const` you can put a function, not just its string name, in an args attribute.  I could have put a different function in its `default` parameter.

```
In [6]: args=parser.parse_args('-d 1234 -f'.split())
In [7]: print(args)
Namespace(d='1234', f=<function foo at 0xac24ca4c>)
```

Note that `args.f` is now a function, not a string.

```
In [8]: if args.f is not None:
   ...:     args.f(args)
   ...:     
Namespace(d='1234', f=<function foo at 0xac24ca4c>)
```

Comment: Only problem I actually see with this option is, I would still have to then do conditional checks of passed arguments, whereas the example below allows for immediately calling a function, but you cant seem to pass the user input.

Comment: Separating the parsing and the dispatching gives you more control.  In the real world, the command line will have other directives, options and arguments that you might want to attend to before running off and doing the `delete/search/list`.

Comment: Can you give some examples? Also, delete, search, etc are just random examples themselves.

Comment: Excellent thank you. I'm not sure I understand yet due to all the formatting, code omission, etc. but I am reading this now and trying to piece it together. Difficult to read for me if not the entire code without all the shorthand. For example IN [X] and namespace etc.

Comment: Sorry, still very new to Python (which is why I am going through all of this).

Comment: I do most of my test coding in an `ipython` session.  It's a little fancier than the regular `python` interactive session.  That's where the `In/Out` headers come from.

Answer (score 1):

The `action` parameter to [`add_argument()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument) does not take arbitrary string values. Rather it gives you a choice of predefined actions. In your case, you probably want to do something like

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example list of options')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--delete', dest='command', action='store_const', const='delete', help='Delete ID')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--search', dest='command', action='store_const', const='search', help='Search ID')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', dest='command', action='store_const', const='list', help='List all ID')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

You can then access `args.command` to check for the operation chosen by the user.

```
if args.command == 'delete':
     ...
elif args.command == 'search':
     ...
```

If there are many functions, one could also:

```
def handle_delete(args):
    pass
# ... as above
args = parser.parse_args()
eval('handle_' + args.command)(args)
```

The `eval` looks up the name `handle_<command>` in the current module and then calls the returned object. Hence for the `delete` command, we call `handle_delete(args)`. Note that you must take care that `command` is not arbitrary Python code.

The other way is to override provide a subclass of `argparse.Action` and override each action's `__call__()` method:

```
class DeleteAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        for value in values:
            print('Deleting {}'.format(value))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-d', nargs=1, action=DeleteAction)
```

Here `values` will contain the arguments to `-d`. Note, however, that `__call__()` will be invoked during parsing.

Comment: This works, but is there no way to call a function instead of jumping through a long list of if statements (assuming multiple options exist)? I figure a function will be more specific and to the point.

Comment: @Atomiklan See above, you can also supply subclass of `Action`. Its `__call__()` method will be called during parsing. And of course, `eval('handle_' + args.command)()` with `def handle_delete(): pass` and so on also works. But be careful not to introduce a security bug that way.

Comment: Unfortunately those topics went over my head. Can you give some examples please?

Answer (score 0):

When calling the argument specified in your program,

```
...
parser.add_argument('-d', '--delete', action='delete', help='DeleteID')
...
```

the option syntax to call the program with that option is

```
nachos.py -d 20394739
# OR
nachos.py --delete 20394739
```